# Closing a menu on an outside click pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm adding a basic functionality to a menu. Whenever the button is clicked the menu toggles from showing to hiding thanks to a css class through Javascript.

However, when ever I try to use this functionality in conjunction with the window.addEventListener, to close the menu on an outside click, it doesn't function. 
What is the reasoning behind it?

Here is the code.

```
<div class="c-wrapper">
  <button type="button" class="c-btn"> Click Me</button>
  <ul class="c-navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Hi there</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hola</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Konichiwa</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would appriciate some help, thanks.

```
.c-wrapper{
  position:relative;
}

.c-btn{
  background-color:royalblue;
  border:none;
  color:white;
  padding:0.5rem 2rem;
  cursor:pointer;
  outline:none;
}


.c-navigation{
  list-style:none;
  background-color:#ccc;
  position:absolute;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:none;


  li{
    margin-top:0.5rem;
  }

  a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    padding:1.4rem;
  }
}


.is-active{
  display:block;
}
```

Here is the Javascript I am mentioning.

```
var button = document.querySelector('.c-btn');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.c-navigation').classList.toggle('is-active');
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
  var menu = document.querySelector('.c-navigation');
  if(event.target != menu && event.target.parentNode != menu){
    menu.style.display='none';
  }
});
```

Comment: The whole code is present here. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
// Get the menu
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target === menu) {
    menu.style.display = "none";
  }
})
```

Better avoid to manipulate styles via JS. Better add a class to menu.

```
menu.classList.add('hidden');
```

And then add a `.hidden` class style to CSS.

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```